# Deleting specific record from an array nested within another array

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a MongoDB record as follow:

```
"id": 1,
"Tasks": [
    {
        "description": "BLAH",
        "Tags": [
            {
                "Name": "test",
                "tagID": "YRG+crq3SJucvlUwTo/uSg=="
            },
            {
                "Name": "Cars",
                "tagID": "ObwiiZpNTOGECgHb1HehHg=="
            }
        ]

    },
    ......
  ]
```

I'm trying to delete the object from 'Tags' with the 'Name: test' by reference to its 'tagID'. The query I have deletes the whole record within 'Tasks' not just that particular Tags object.

```
db.user.update({ 'id': 1 }, 
    { 
        '$pull': { 'Tasks': {'Tags.tagID': "YRG+crq3SJucvlUwTo/uSg==" }}
    },
    { '$multi': 'true' }
)
```

How can I ammend my query to only remove that particular tag and not remove the entire record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Pymongo` and the [**`$`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) operator

```
col.update({"id": 1, "Tasks.description": "BLAH"},
    {
           "$pull": {"Tasks.$.Tags" : { "tagID": "YRG+crq3SJucvlUwTo/uSg==" }}
    }, multi=True 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the **[positional operator `$`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/)** together with the **`$pull`** update operator to remove the specific array element object:

```
db.user.update({"id": 1, "Tasks.description": "BLAH"},
   {
       "$pull": {"Tasks.$.Tags" : { "tagID": "YRG+crq3SJucvlUwTo/uSg==" }}
   },
   { multi: true}
);
```

Comment: I think it is `multi` not `$multi`

Comment: @Michael You are correct, thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the `$unset` command. Reference [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/).